# Rails 5 Test Case - Getting SQLite3::ConstraintException error when running test on controller that doesn't use model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, sqlite

Im sorry if this might be long but would appreciate your help on this.

I'm getting error when running test on my home controller.

This is my home controller which just basically renders the view.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

And in my test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
class HomeControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    test "should get index" do
        get home_index_url
        assert_response :success
    end
end
```

When i run *bin/rails test test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb* in the terminal, im getting this error as a result

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 27352
Run options: --seed 1283

# Running:

E

Error:
HomeControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL
constraint failed: addresses.full_address: INSERT INTO "addresses" 
("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2017-07-31 11:49:24.912600', 
'2017-07-31 11:49:24.912600', 980190962)

bin/rails test test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:4

Finished in 0.595890s, 1.6782 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

I have a model called Address but it's not used in the home controller. Here is how my Address migration file looks like

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string :full_address, null: false
      t.string :formatted_address
      t.string :sub_locality
      t.string :city
      t.string :postal_code
      t.string :state
      t.decimal :latitude, precision: 9, scale:6
      t.decimal :longitude, precision: 9, scale:6
      t.references :user
      t.references :order
      t.references :merchant

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
 end
```

From my understanding, the test result would return success if the http response is 200. In my browser, i can load my home page without any errors in my log.

Im confused as to why i'm getting Address model related error when i'm testing my home controller even though i did not access it in my home controller or view.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an invalid fixture? Check in `test/fixtures/addresses.yml`

Comment: Turns out the issue was caused by the invalid fixtures. Thank you for your help Aaron!